# Missing information in XML file

Tags: xml

I'm a Python beginner so I need your help. I have an XML file as input like this:
<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order 'xmlns:xsd="sample 1" 'xmlns:xsi="sample 2" number="sample 3" name="sample 4">
#The rest of XML...
</order>
```

After running the code to modify the content of XML file which working well except one thing.
The line 2 misses some namespaces and their values. The output will be like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<order number="sample 3" name="sample 4">
#The rest of XML...
</order>
```

As you can see, the xmlns:xsd="sample 1" xmlns:xsi="sample 2" are disappear. So please help me to fix it, I will be very appreciated with your help. Thank you.
Here's my full code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

# Enter the directory path of excel and xml files
directory_path = input('Enter the directory path: ')

# Search for Excel files in the directory using glob
excel_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.xlsx"))
for excel_file in excel_files:
    excel_name = os.path.basename(excel_file)

# Search for XML files in the directory using glob
xml_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.xml"))
xml_names = []
for xml_file in xml_files:
    xml_names.append(os.path.basename(xml_file))


    
#Set data for XML from Excel
for xml in xml_names:
    # Read the Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_name)

    # Read the XML file
    tree = ET.parse(xml)
    root = tree.getroot()
    ET.register_namespace('xsd','sample 1')
    ET.register_namespace('xsi', 'sample 2')


    # Loop through each position element
    for position in root.findall('position'):
        for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
            # Check if the position name matches the data in the Excel file
            if position.get('name') == df['position_name'][i]:
                for conn in position.findall('conn'):
                    connector_num = conn.get('number')
                    if pd.notna(df[f'SAMPLE PARAMETER {connector_num}'][i]):
                        conn.set('key', str(int(df[f'SAMPLE PARAMETER {connector_num}'][i])))

    # Write the updated XML file to disk
    tree.write('updated_'+xml, xml_declaration= True, encoding="utf-8")
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfZRc.png)

Comment: It is better to use XSLT callable from Python for any XML transformations.

Comment: Can you share the code that's modifying the file? It's not possible to help you without knowing the actual code you're running.

Comment: @EricHasegawa I've updated the full code in the post. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Can you explain more? I don't know what XSLT callable is.

Comment: XSLT is a native and most powerful XML API for any XML transformations. XSLT is language agnostic, and callable from any language: Python, c#, Java, JavaScript, PowerShell, etc.